Tight-binding computer program with electron thermodynamics
Does anyone know of a computer program which implements the Slater-Koster tight-binding scheme and which uses the resultant band structure to calculate thermodynamic state functions for the electrons (specifically, the free energy and entropy)? I'm aware of PythTB and Tight-Binding Studio, but these don't seem to handle thermodynamics. I'm essentially looking for the analogue of the General Utility Lattice Program (GULP) for the electronic degrees of freedom, if one exists. I'd like to stay away from DFT solutions. Thank you!

Probably what you want is something like 'density functional tight binding' (DFTB). The total energy, free energy, etc. contain contributions from the Hartree potential, XC, ion-ion interactions, etc., not just the band energy. A simple Slater-Koster (SK) code will usually only give you band structure, which isn't enough to calculate total energy.
In DFTB, the other contributions are approximated with pair potentials or other ways, so that the total energy, forces, etc. are available at very little additional computational cost over simple SK tight-binding. The new challenge is there are more parameters to fit or calculate for the other contributions to the energy. I think for many materials, these parameters are already available. See e.g. here.
For codes, see e.g. here.
Others may have better suggestions, but I hope this helps :)
Ty
